# Dropdown Filter and Display

Tags: php, html, mysql

I've created a dropdown that pulls data from my database:

```
//Selecting Product Name for Dropdown
$sql = "SELECT DISTINCT TypeOther FROM PedalDirectory";
$rs = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
echo "<select>";
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($rs)){
echo "<option value='".$row["TypeOther"]."'>".$row["TypeOther"]."</option>";
}mysql_free_result($rs);
echo "</select>";
```

but im not sure how to get the dropdown menu to show the information from the database.  tried a couple things but seems i can only get all the records to display.

What I would like to do is, when you select an item from the dropdown menu I want that record to appear on the page.

any helps appreciated.

Comment: What's showing up now? I'm having a bit of trouble understanding what you mean by *"but seems i can only get all the records to display"*. What is it exactly that you want shown?

Comment: my apologies.

when you select an item from the dropdown menu i want that record(s) to appear on the page.

something like this: http://www.w3schools.com/php/showphp.asp?filename=demo_ajax_mysql

except i dont want to manually enter the values, id want them coming from the database

Comment: They are coming from the DB in that link. The SQL is inside the "getuser.php" file. You'll need to look further inside that website which it is in there. Ajax would be a good method to use. If you must, look at http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_ajax_database.asp

Comment: thanks. i've got it partially working. still not able to have the dropdown list populate from the DB though.

Comment: You're welcome. You will need to select more columns, rather than just `TypeOther` in order for the other fields to appear.

Comment: do i insert the dropdown code into the getusers.php file?  the php just displays as text if i place it into the .html document, even if its in the <?php ?> tags

Comment: Copy their example files exactly as shown. Just modify the codes for the table and column names.

Answer (score 0):

> Suppose your dropdown is like

```
<select id="drop">
     <option value="">Select one...</option>
     <option value="11">11</option>
     <option value="12">12</option>
     <option value="13">13</option>
     <option value="14">14</option>
</select>
```

> Use jQuery to get selected value

```
$("#drop").change(function () {
     var end = this.value;
     alert(end);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks all. I figured it out.

```
<form>

<?php
//Selecting Pedal Type for Dropdown
$sql = "SELECT * FROM PedalDirectory";
$rs = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
echo '<select onchange="showUser(this.value)">';
echo '<option value="">Select a pedal type:</option>';
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($rs)){
echo "<option value='".$row["PedalID"]."'>".$row["Type"]."</option>";
}mysql_free_result($rs);
echo "</select>";
  ?>
</form>
```